# How to use session in wordpress in plugin development

Tags: wordpress, php

I am new to write a plugin ..I am having a testplugin.php file and a ajax.php file ..

My code in testplugin.php is

```
global $session;

print_r($abc); //$abc is array of my data ..

$session['arrayImg']=$abc; //saving data in session 

echo  $session['arrayImg']; //displayin "Array"
```

And my ajax.php consists of following code

```
global $session;

$abc = $session['arrayImg'];

print_r ("abs== ".$abc); //displayin "abs== Array"
```

And if use `session_start();`

I get following error

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

I just want to send array of data from one file of my plugin to another file ...

Comment: start the session in init hook

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### Add following on your plugin or themes `functions.php` file

```php
function wpse16119876_init_session() {
    if ( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
// Start session on init hook.
add_action( 'init', 'wpse16119876_init_session' );
```

#### Next, to add data in `SESSION` -

```php
// If session has started, this data will be stored.
$_SESSION['arrayImg'] = $abc;
```

#### To get the data on ajax hooked function -

```php
// handle the ajax request
function wpse16119876_handle_ajax_request() {
    if ( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }

    if ( array_key_exists( 'arrayImg', $_SESSION ) ) {
        $abc = $_SESSION['arrayImg'];
    } else {
        $abc = 'NOT IN SESSION DATA';
    }

    // Do something with $abc
}
```

Comment: Lets have a party :) @jcwenger

Comment: How to destroy the session when no longer used ?

Comment: To destroy, use `$_SESSION['arrayImg'] = '';` or `unset($_SESSION['arrayImg'])` . And to destroy the complete $SESSION data, use [session_destroy](http://bd1.php.net/session_destroy)

Comment: Using this solution, I get this error: "Cannot start session when headers already sent"

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using that session variable in plugin activation as well. So did something unorthodox. Instead of defining my session_start in a hook I made it as the first line in my plugin :).

To heck with plugins, as soon as wordpress scans through my file it initiates the session.

At the end I do not destroy the session on user logout. I simply unset my variable. This is to just in case if some other plugin is also using session. If I destroy session it may affect other plugins.

Cheers.