# cant get http_referer to stay in session

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables, http-referer

I have been searching for hours and cant find the answer to this one.

I am trying to add the referring url to an email message (form sent by visitor on the website)  so I can know what website the visitor was referred from. (part of ongoing analytic).

I am trying to set the SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] into a session like so..

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["inbound"])) { 
    $_SESSION["inbound"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
 }
```

but the session keeps changing every time another page is loaded. I presumed putting the ! before isset would tell it that there is already a session and not to try adding it again.

I have also tried it this way (and a combinations of other ways):

```
if(isset($_SESSION["inbound"])) { 
    // do nothing 
} else { 
    $_SESSION["inbound"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
}
```

I am doing this in WordPress, but I dont think that should be an issue. I have used sessions in Wordpress many times before without any problems.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks
Eoin

UPDATE: Have tried it like this:

```
function get_ref_session() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION["inbound"])) { 
        $the_referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
        $_SESSION["inbound"] = $the_referer; 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_ref_session' );
```

No joy this way either :(

Tried this in the plugin and in functions.php, no joy. (at the top)

```
function register_session(){
    if( !session_id() )
        session_start();
}
add_action('init','register_session');
```

Comment: You're checking for $_SESSION["inbound"] but setting $_SESSION["origURL"]. Perhaps that's it?

Comment: In your first code sample, you're mixing keys `inbound` and `origURL`. Make double-sure that's not your problem. (I find it helpful to use constants for things like this.)

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress does not use PHP sessions by default. It directly sets cookies to manage its own sessions.
You need to include `session_start();` before any header information is sent. Otherwise no session data will be saved.

[How to use session in wordpress in plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118817/how-to-use-session-in-wordpress-in-plugin-development)

```
function register_session(){
    if( !session_id() )
        session_start();
}
add_action('init','register_session');
```

Comment: Also please be careful when using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], it's not always available and it can be altered by the user

Comment: I have session_start() at the top, but no joy :(

Comment: Yeah, http_referrer is not 100% but it will do the job for this.

Comment: at the top? you mean at the top of your function that is run during the init hook like OP suggested.. right?

Comment: Just to add to the above.. I have another session that gets its value from a $_GET[''], which is working on the same site just fine. Im 100% sure, but the the http_referer one, its seems to be more of an issue with the if(isset). Its like its being ignored or something.

Comment: I have never tried doing this in a non-plugin environment, but this does work for plugins. The only other place I can guarantee it would work would be to hack `index.php` and put it there (which could be overwritten when you upgrade)

Comment: I had this in my function at one stage, if ( !session_id() ) {
add_action( 'init', 'session_start' );
}

Answer (score 0):

After a big more digging, turns out that its caching of the pages that are preventing the sessions from working properly..

When logged into wordpress sessions work fine, but when logged out (which all the visitors will be) they don't work.

Think im gonna have to look into doing this with cookies instead.