# $_SESSION not working if user is not logged in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I want to store value in session even user is not logged-in in WordPress. I have tried below coder but it is not working. If user is logged in then it is working.

```
$old_data = $_SESSION['wc_pd_customizetion_data'];
$old_data[$product_id] =  $extra_data;
$_SESSION['wc_pd_customizetion_data'] = $old_data;
```

Comment: Wordpress does not use sessions. You have to add `session_start()` via plugin or other method (hook).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use session in wordpress in plugin development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118817/how-to-use-session-in-wordpress-in-plugin-development)

Comment: I have already added below code.
add_action( 'init', array($this,'start_session' )); 
function start_session() {
 if ( ! session_id()) {
     session_start();
 }
}

Comment: set this session_start();  above $old_data and try

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I found another Stackoverflow user that found the answer for the same problem that I was encountering :

In my case, it was the web hosting's Varnish that was interferring with Sessions.

Disabling Varnish fixed the problem !

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42554066/302258