# How do I retain session variables in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have been developing a custom dashboard inside a Wordpress page template without ever calling get_header or get_footer and I have been experiencing issues with SESSION variables.

It seems to be randomly keeping/deleting them.

Here is my very simple code snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';

?>
```

This small snippet should print an empty array on the first try and the test variable after that.

Instead what it does is print the variable on random intervals. By refreshing the page 20 times ~4 of the you can see the variables and the rest 16 it's empty.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use session in wordpress in plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118817/how-to-use-session-in-wordpress-in-plugin-development)

Comment: You did some research? Probably not! Plenty of articles about your issue even on stackoverflow! - https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

To set a session you have to make sure headers haven't been set, and also include `session_write_close()` otherwise some loopback functions in WordPress will fail.  Neither of the referenced answers mention this little tidbit about the session_write_close.

```
function dd_register_session(){
    if(!session_id() && !headers_sent()) {
        session_start();
        session_write_close();
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','dd_register_session', 1);

add_action('wp_logout', 'end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'end_session');
add_action('end_session_action', 'end_session');

function end_session() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/transients/) instead. In Wordpress it is highly recommended to use it instead of Session.

```
set_transient( $transient, $value, $expiration );
get_transient( $transient );
delete_transient( $transient );
```