# Contact Form 7 retrive $_SESSION in a input

Tags: php, wordpress

I would need to insert within an input value, the value coming from a $ _SESSION, searching on google I found this regarding cookies:

functions:

```
function sb_cf7_cookie($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'key' => -1,
    ), $atts));

    if($key == -1) return '';
    $val = '';

    if( isset( $_COOKIE[$key] ) ){
        $val = $_COOKIE[$key];
    }

    return $val;
}
add_shortcode('SB_CF7_COOKIE', 'sb_cf7_cookie');
```

in cf7:

```
[dynamichidden field-name "SB_CF7_COOKIE key='COOKIE_NAME'"]
```

how can make this with $`_SESSION`?

this is my code for `$_SESSION`

```
function dd_register_session(){
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
        if($_GET['r']){
            $_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];
        }
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','dd_register_session', 1);


add_action('wp_logout', 'end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'end_session');
add_action('end_session_action', 'end_session');

function end_session() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: For adding a session, you first need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386219/how-do-i-retain-session-variables-in-wordpress/64390108#64390108

Comment: Why are you putting `$_SESSION['referrer']` but in your shortcode you want `$_COOKIE[$key]`

Comment: @HowardE because it's an example, was to say I would like to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this by rolling your own form tag.  Add this to your theme functions.php

To use this, the form tag name would be the name of the session variable. So, if you're looking for `$_SESSION['referrer']` then the form tag name should be `referrer`

So the form tag in the contact form would be `[session_var referrer]`

In the email you would put [referrer].

```
add_action('wpcf7_init', function (){
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'session_var' , 'cf7_session_variable_callback', array('name-attr' => true) );
}); 
function cf7_session_variable_callback($tag){
  $tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );
  $value = (!empty($_SESSION[$tag->name])) ? $_SESSION[$tag->name] : 'not set';
  $output = '<input type="hidden" name="'.$tag->name.'" value="'.$value.'">';
  return $output;
}
```