# php, wordpress - I am handling data from one page to another with php session. Is it good and secure?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In wordpress I am using a plugin for booking and I want to display booking data on thank you page. Thank you page has custom template. I customized the plugin and before redirecting it will store booking and user info into session. After redirect on thank you page I will get info from session and after that, I will destroy the session. I am also using session variable "is_booked" to check if user booked service and if user didn't it will redirect him to the homepage. My question is,  is it safe to store user information into a session. And if I am using it the right way.

**Php code in plugin that I customized**

```php
session_start();    
$_SESSION['is_booked'] = true; 
$_SESSION['bookig_id'] = $bookingId;
$_SESSION['client_full_name'] = $client_full_name;
...
```

**Php custom thank-you-page template code**

```php
<?php
/*
Template Name: thankyoupage
*/
session_start();


 if (!isset($_SESSION['is_booked'])){

    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
}

else {
 
get_header();
?>

<style>
MY STYLE
</style>

HERE IS MY HTML


<?php
} 
session_destroy();
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use session in wordpress in plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118817/how-to-use-session-in-wordpress-in-plugin-development)

Answer (score 0):

It’s acceptable to save information that is not sensitive such as booking IDs or names, but any personal data should be encrypted. Session usage appears to be appropriate based on your description. You're utilising them to store non-sensitive records and properly discarding them after usage.

**Alternative Approaches:** Check if you can use WordPress's existing features and services. Transients or custom user meta, for example, could be used to hold transitory data. These are built into WordPress and have been optimized for speed and security.

> Transients API, which offers a simple and standardized way of storing
> cached data in the database temporarily by giving it a custom name and
> a timeframe after which it will expire and be deleted.
>
> The Transients API is very similar to the Options API but with the
> added feature of an expiration time, which simplifies the process of
> using the wp_options database table to temporarily store cached
> information.
>
> Note that the “site_” functions are essentially the same as their
> counterparts, but work network wide when using WordPress Multisite.
>
> Also of note is that Transients are inherently sped up by caching
> plugins, where normal Options are not. A memcached plugin, for
> example, would make WordPress store transient values in fast memory
> instead of in the database. For this reason, transients should be used
> to store any data that is expected to expire, or which can expire at
> any time. Transients should also never be assumed to be in the
> database, since they may not be stored there at all.

[Read about it here more](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/transients/)

Comment: Ok, so if I am also storing customer email and phone number I should encrypt it, or use a different way?

Comment: @Starship Personally, I would do it in a way where obtaining sensitive data from the server database, would be done by saving just a reference ID or token. This will restrict the amount of private information exposed through direct session storage. And if you still decide to go with SESSION - use PHP's openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt functions to encrypt private information such as emails and phone numbers. To secure data transmission, use HTTPS and take precautions against vulnerabilities such as session hijacking.